# Swift 4: kill executing thread with called c++ bridge function

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I have c++ API, which is connected via bridge file. Inside this API, there is a function which, to my regret, has infinite loop that waits for the data arriving.

I call this function, when user click on start button, via:

```
   workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
     foo()
   }
   DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async(execute: workItem!)
```

The function fill variables inside c++ algo, in particular, arrays of provided data.

When user click on stop button, I stop this thread with:

```
self.workItem?.cancel()
```

The only problem is that it is not kills this thread and clean memory. I know this, because when user clicks start button again, it continues to work with old data in c++ arrays

Is there is a way to kill this particular thread and clean memory, in order on each start/stop the user will start the new session

Answer (score 0):

As far as GCD is concerned, WorkItem Cancel is nothing but equivalent of [dispatch_block_cancel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1431058-dispatch_block_cancel).

Drawing from that analogy, blocks that have already started execution do not halt. Only the workitems that are pending for execution can potentially be stopped.

Upon stop, you may have to manually Undo what WorkItem actually did, if it has already executed it before.